# vercel deployment failed: Host key verification failed

Tags: github, deployment, next.js, vercel

I got this error when deploying a project on vercel. I have 4 other projects hosted on vercel and never had this issue before:

```
warning Pattern ["ethereumjs-abi@git+https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-abi.git"]
is trying to unpack in the same destination 
"/vercel/.cache/yarn/v6/npm-ethereumjs-abi-0.6.8-ee3994657fa7a427238e6ba92a84d0b529bbcde0/node_modules/ethereumjs-abi" 
as pattern ["ethereumjs-abi@^0.6.8"]. This could result in non-deterministic behavior, skipping.

error Command failed.
Exit code: 128
Command: git
Arguments: ls-remote --tags --heads ssh://git@github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-abi.git
Directory: /vercel/path0

Output:
   Host key verification failed.
   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

 Please make sure you have the correct access rights
 and the repository exists.
 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
Error: Command "yarn install" exited with 128
```

- deleted the `package-lock.json` and tried it
- I made sure dev dependencies are correctly separated from dependencies.

BUt still same error. I could successfully build with

```
 npm run build
 yarn build
```

locally.

Answer (score 1):

In your package.json you will have this dependency:

```
"ethereumjs-abi": "github:ethereumjs/ethereumjs-abi"
```

This kind of reference defaults to access github over ssh, but github have deprecated this mode of access. Instead you should use https like this:

```
"ethereumjs-abi": "https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-abi"
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was deleting my git repository using:

```html
rm -fr .git
```

and initializing a new repository in the same directory but this time I didn't use npm , instead used yarn. So make sure to delete package-lock.json and node modules and then run :

```html
yarn
```